# How to add new list when I click on the current list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to do when I click on icon add, it will generate a list of array which I have declare. The list have its own container which have different header 'Surat Rasmi permohonan, surat lantikan peguam'.  my current problem is the 3 list comes at once and wrong method on calling my 'header'. Here is my coding. Please refer to it.

Hoping someone can enlighten and help me on this. I am using stateful widget for my UploadDoc function.

[image]

[image]

```
    class UploadDoc extends StatefulWidget {
  const UploadDoc({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UploadDoc> createState() =>  _UploadDocState();
}

class _UploadDocState extends State<UploadDoc> {

  final List<dynamic> listSelection = [
    { 
      'id': 0, 
      'header':'Surat Rasmi Permohonan', 
      'title': 'Muat Naik Surat Rasmi',
    },
     { 
      'id': 1, 
      'header':'Surat Lantikan Peguam',  
      'title': 'Muat Naik Surat Rasmi',
    },
     { 
      'id': 2, 
      'header':'Surat hubungan peguam dan pemilik daftar', 
      'title': 'Muat Naik Surat Rasmi',
    },
  ];
  
  dynamic _selected = 0;
  int index = 0;
  //int _count =0;
  //late List<Widget> _upload = new List.generate(_count, (int i) =>  UploadDoc());

void add() { 
  setState(() {
    listSelection.insert(0, 0);
  });
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children:  [
          SizedBox(
            height: 200.0, 
            width: 400.0,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: listSelection.length, 
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {   
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 30,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Text(listSelection[index]['header'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        ],
                      )
                    ),
                    ListTile( 
                      title: Text(listSelection[index]['title']),
                      leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline), 
                      onPressed: add,
              ),
                )] ,
                );
              },
            ),
          ), 
          const Divider(thickness: 1)
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So in your example, you want to add 3 elements everytime you tap on the button ?

Comment: Yes sir @DanielRoldán

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't declare anything inside `build` method. Theses variable will reinitialize on state change. Better approach is using [`ListView.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html). while you like to have separator, use [`ListView.separated`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.custom.html).

Next important things to control the index range on count increment,

```dart
class _UploadDocState extends State<UploadDoc> {
  final List<dynamic> listSelection = [
    {
      'id': 0,
      'header': 'Muat Naik Surat Rasmi Permohonan',
      'icon': Icon(Icons.add_circle_outlined),
      'title': 'Muat Naik Surat Rasmi',
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'header': 'Surat Lantikan Peguam',
      'icon': Icon(Icons.add_circle_outlined),
      'title': 'test',
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'header': 'Surat hubungan peguam dan pemilik daftar',
      'icon': Icon(Icons.add_circle_outlined),
      'title': 'test',
    },
  ];

  int _selected = 0;
  int index = 0;
  int _count = 1;
  late List<Widget> _upload = List.generate(_count, (int i) => UploadDoc());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: _count,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 30,
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Text(listSelection[index]['header'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ],
                )),
            ListTile(
              leading: listSelection[index]['icon'],
              title: Text(listSelection[index]['header']),
              onTap: _addNewUploadDoc,
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(thickness: 1),
    );
  }

  void _addNewUploadDoc() {
    setState(() {
      if (_count < listSelection.length) {
        _count = _count + 1;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: try your code but I got blank screen @yeasinsheikh

Comment: Can you include how you are using this Widget, if it is in `Column` wrap this widget with `Expanded(child":UploadDoc())`

Comment: actually sir, I want to do when I click on icon add, it will generate a list of array which I have declare. The list have its own container which have different header 'Surat Rasmi permohonan, surat lantikan peguam'

Comment: I think I have wrong declare list tile, which it should be in column, can you help me sir

Comment: i already edit my question

Comment: Do you like to have  [this](https://dartpad.dev/?id=7b04d1546387d5c26dc8169848cc60bb)  or item will be added just under  the header;

Comment: yes sir like that. thank you so much for helping me and I appreciate it! wish you all the best in future

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommed to declare Icon inside of Map<String, dynamic> since all icons are identical. Instead use icon directly inside ListTile. The below code adds 1 item for each. If you want to add all items at once, you can change _addNewUploadDoc to

```
void _addNewUploadDoc() {
  if(listSelection.length != selected.length){
    for (int i = 0; i < listSelection.length-1; i++) {
      selected.add(listSelection[i]);
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UploadDoc extends StatefulWidget {
  const UploadDoc({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UploadDoc> createState() => _UploadDocState();
}

class _UploadDocState extends State<UploadDoc> {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> listSelection = [
    {
      'id': 0,
      'header': 'Muat Naik Surat Rasmi Permohonan',
      'title': 'Muat Naik Surat Rasmi',
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'header': 'Surat Lantikan Peguam',
      'title': 'test',
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'header': 'Surat hubungan peguam dan pemilik daftar',
      'title': 'test',
    },
  ];
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> selected = [];

  // 'icon': const Icon(Icons.add_circle_outlined),
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (selected.isEmpty) {
    selected.add(listSelection[0]);
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: selected.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 30,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text(listSelection[index]['header'],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ],
                  )),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.add_circle_outlined),
                title: Text(listSelection[index]['header']),
                onTap: () => _addNewUploadDoc(),
              ),
              const Divider(thickness: 1)
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addNewUploadDoc() {
    setState(() {
      print('_addNewUploadDzzoc');
      print(selected.length);
      print(listSelection.length);
      if (listSelection.length > selected.length) {
        selected.add(listSelection[selected.length]);

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: sir why after run, it turned blank screen @behzodfaiziev

Comment: Here is the [code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=72fbe4720193ebefb690a04bd1b3feab). Seems it works fine